# Infinite Non-ASCII character in the Angular ng test output

Tags: angular, jasmine

I've updated my Angular project (it's a library) from 11 to 13 and now, I get an infinite sequence of non-ASCII characters when I run the `ng test` command.

The output of the command:

```
                                   !             H|H|H|H|H           H__________________________________             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|§|∞|§|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|§|§|§|H           H|* * * * * *|---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H| * * * * * |---------------------|             H|H|H|H|H           H|---------------------------------|          ===============        H|---------------------------------|            /| _   _ |          H|---------------------------------|            (| O   O |)          H|---------------------------------|            /|   U   |          H-----------------------------------             |  =/  |           H              _..._/            H              _|I/|_            H      _______/| H |/_______    H     /           / /          H    |          | | /         |  H    |          ||o||          |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H    |    |     ||o||     |    |  H   Carl Pilcher  
ẗ̨̨̩̪̭͍͖͓̩̣̺̗̼̲͈̼̺͕̦̝̠̠̲͔̀̈̒̏̾ͪ̍̋̊̒̄ͣ̂̀ͅeͮ̌̅̿͊̚͞ ҉̶ ҉̦͙͎̦̯̻̗̠̠̹̣̠̹͕̩̥̟͙̱͎̠͇̩͎̞̜̰͖͓̟ͅs̸̶̢̛̙̫͓͚̫͚̠̳͔͍͔̮͍̟̟͕̼͙͙̗͂̔͑̿͛͂t̸̸̶̯͔̼͈͈̯̠͖̭̜̙̾͆ͤ̓ͧ̅́ͤ̎͗͌̂̆̇ͤ́͠i̧͕̙̟̦̥̟̭͚͈̜̼̘̙̜̼͍͓̱̙̻̬̗̖̜̲͖ͭ͗̆͊̀͝ń̡̡͕̲̬̮̣̟͇̙̳͖͔̼̼̫̮̩̜̯̫̪̫̞̙̹̉ͩ̑ͧͭ͐̒̄̃̋ͮͬ͜͟g̴̻̫̘̬̺͓̳̞̫͇͙̙̻͓͔̭͈̋ͧ̌̍͛ͯͧ̂ͣ̈͊̽̈̎̀̀͝ͅ ̛͉͇̭̝̥̜͚̼̱̬͖̣̥̠͙̦̻͉͙ͭ̇̔̂ͫ͋ͪͭͮ͜͠ẗ̵͇̼̭̞̥̲͙̠̫̺͈̯̠͔̮̞͍̹̺̗͓̻̝̦͖̰̖̤̞̺͍̜͓̞̻̪̻͇̎͐ͩͧ̐͛̑̓̉ͯ͑́ͤ̈̂̓͜͡ͅͅͅḙ̴̥̹͖͎̝͖͍̩͉̼̠̝̣̰̳̝̣̰̟̱̣̰̜̖̗͔̣̦͉̪̝͕͍̭͉͍̳͕̮͖̣̱̓̅ͤ̽ͬͮͣ̂ͩ͐͛̋̓͛ͦ̓̽̓͘͝͠ͅͅs̏͌̂̿ͥͤ̒̋͟ ҉̱̹̹̟̲̯̳̻̣͔͖̰̫̩͇̫͖̦̱͍̳̗̮̭̗̥̪̮͇̠̲̦͉̱͇̫̮̩̲̘̼͇̟̠̤̹̞̼̱̝̮͔̠̪͙͈͉͖͙͢͝ͅt̡̝̬̯̗͍̠̦͎̝͇̤̼ͨ̉ͯ́̉̈ͣͣ̽̈ͤ̈̂̃ͦ͑͠į̼͚̙̗͇̙͍̖̤͕̺̫̖̰̱̦̫̻̙̫̘͕͚̖͔̩͍͉̥͓͈̹̜̼̖͙̲̄̒͂ͩ̽͌̌͒ͩ͆͂͌̊̓́͑̃̚͜͢ͅn̶̡̗̭͈͔̪̩̹̱ͯ̍̇ͥͦ͒͆ͨ͛̐̎͞g̨̢̢͙̬̥̼̜̽͌̈ͧ͟͡ ̵͔͚͍̳͎̩̦̼͉͕̥̖͉̭̠̥̮̫̂̊̄͆ͦ͐͂̎́ͮ̈͛̎̐ͨͭ͡t̨̹̼͔͎̝̠̖͖̺͉͓͍̬̲͚͓̖̫̺͓̻͍̙͙̜̤̱̤̮̲̠̯͉͙͍̼̞͉̳̗̻̖̭̣͔̲͙̫̱̟̜͙̦̥̥̠̰͎͚̰͎͙̳̓̍͌ͩͪͣ͐̂͋̉͗̓̇ͬ̓ͫ̿ͧ͟͡ͅȩ͉̗͍̫͖͈͕̪̓̀ͣͥ̀ͅs̷̞͈̠̺͔̲̝̣̩̠̫̩̻͙̬͓͇̲̘̮͕̲̮͉ͬ̐̈̔̋̐ͯ̚͘͝ͅť̳͇̲̼̻̱̥̤̭̺̣͖̯̦̝̝̠̤̦̟̬̩͉̮̟̘́͌̈ͦͥ̈̉̒̉̔̿͊̏͆̍ͪ͘͟ͅͅį̶̺͔̹͔̭̟̪̦̬͍̼͍̼͕̙̞̬̪̜̭̱̰͇͉͎̭͚̩͍̖̜̹̱͖̼̖̜̱͔͇̠̪͓͎̣͙̟͚͓͊̃̎͌ͤ̽͛̊̎ͧͅn̷̛̛̺̲̻͚̬̭̹̙̠̥̱̜͈̠͖̦̺̹͕͚̺͓̰̤̒ͬ̍̄ͥͨͮ̌̈̓͐̔̂̒̀͝͞g̵̸̼͉͖̮̙̬̮̹̭͔̖̪̠̦̰̠̼͓̼͇̯̤͈̭̤̺͉̭̗̰̦͓͓̤̟̝̙̺͙̯̙̱̜̹̹̬̼̤̯̱̺͂̌ͪ̑ͨ̔ͭ͊ͨ̓̓̃ͥ̍͢͞ ͣ̉̑̍̋͒̀̈͂ͪͯ͆̾ͮͦ̓ͫ͡ ҉̸̧͔̼̰̬͉̖̭͖̮̣͖͎̬̟̻̤͉̰͍̭̖͙̻̖̠̭̦͓͙̝̺̲͍̻̳̟͉̙̤͎̥̙̺͍̮͉̲͖͎͇͚̜͞t̶̸̴̛̬̜̼͍̬̬͚̠̼̺͕̝͇͔͓͈͓̤̹̙̟͉̘̻̹̭̪̞͖̫̰̣̱̭͙̼͈̪̮͉̍ͧ̉ͦ͒̈̉̾̏͗͌̓͒̀̚ͅe̸̷͓̖͉̫͓̤͍̩͙̺̦̦̬̭̞̞͚̳̪̘̥̟̫͈̘̦̠̤̙̖̰͆̍̆͐̐́͟ͅş̥̝̙͍̤̤͍̙̘̺̩͎̜̤̭̼͕͙̝͉̟͓̥͓̦͍͕̟͚̜̱͓̤̣̭͇̭̬̮̲͖̱̓̔̔̔ͧ̀͐ͫ́͊̀͘͜͝t̵̷̵͙̯̜̳̣̹̙̱̤̰̣͇̭̖̜̩̗̝̳̭̣̽̐ͦ̑ͨ̍ï̧͖̘͇̻͎͖͓̪̝̦̹̹͇͓̗̤̭͍͕͕̠̥̪̺͓̮̠̭̯̤̲̮̘̺͇̭̼̥͉ͣ͐̑̏̓͌̋̽̀̇͋̾̈̒̓̊͐̚͜͝ͅn̶̤̜̹̗̗̙̠̭̯̦̫̞̬̳͔̗͉̥̘͈̹̫̫̾͑͑̅ͪ͑̂̈̔̇͐́̓ͤͩ́̕͞ͅg̵̷͖̪̤̰͖̦͚̦̗̞̙̤͈̯̮̯͖̲̠̱̝̥͕̯̱̦̻̜̟̖̼̜̠͕̟̳̠̟̘͉͖̙̖̫̼̻̪̼̹͕̖̜̗͉͉̤̤͕͕̎ͥͨͦ̋̄ͭ̈̎͗͗̓̈͋̆ͥ̇͢ ̵̡͖͓̯̫̻̘̹̰̺̰̖͔̤̦̝̥̜̩̤̙̤̝̜̖̯̗̼͈ͪͤ̂͋͒ͬ́̾̒ͧ͊̾ͭͫͩͯ̓̚̚͠͠͞ͅt̶̶̫̺̙̥͉͎̝̦̱̭̗̗͉̘̫̗̮͙̻͙͈̮͈̭̝̻̘͇̥̣̦̮͈̞̙͙̫͉͖ͦͥͮͮ͒̃͝ě̼̬̼͇̯̟̬͚̑̑̾́̇ͧ̎̾̃̽ͬ̊͂͊͋͠͠ͅs̶̴̛͖̫̺̝̙̺͇̫͎̭̹̠̮̫͔͙̯̱̤̳̰͍̼͈̬̩̪̝̳̞̫͎͙̰̹̪͎̲̲̹̯͕̲̗͙͙͔̰̼̖͔͔̱̯͈̤̪̱͔ͭ͑̾̐ͨͩͬ̉́̇̓ͬ͗͆ͫ̒ͮ͊͜͝ͅṱ̜̝̲̠͉̻̭̳̝̞̘̰͓͚̠̼̩̤̪͔͚̥̣̥̟̜͕̤ͩ͗͗͗̀́̕͘͞ͅͅi̶̛͎̪̻̜̪̗̘̜̞͚̣̥̻͖͈̞͍͎̳̥̠̣͎̩̱͚̺̯̬̤̘̖̥̼̘̗̓ͣ͗̀ͫͮ̉̄̿ͩͨ̅̏̊ͦ̂͊̉̚͞͝͡n͇͎̦̼͚͖̩̜̱̘̫͇͎͈͔̜̤̟̞̼̰̖̟̹̲̱̝͉̦̰̼̝̯͙̤͕̟̹̯͔̦͉͙͙̞͈̼̯͕̭̳̳̭͙̭̘̖͉̰͓͓̬̯̉̂̃̈̇̾̑̓ͨ̅̒̊̈̚͜͡ͅͅͅg̸̴̠̯̲̞̱̜̱̹̼͓̈ͧͣͮ̍͆̍́͜ ̴̡̻̳͉̭̜̜̩̠͖̖͇̲̺̠̖̲͖͙͉̹̞̯̖̬̜̼̹̖̭̣̥͍̺̖͍̘̬̜̜͖͔̜͈̲͎͓͚̫̹̳̍ͭ̑ͫ̀̚͟t̨́̿̎̌ͥ̇͑ͩͪ̎͌̌̉̇̌̓̚ ҉̥͔̙̙̤͍̙͈̘͕̫͎͖͍̲̱͘ͅeͥ̍̏̀̈̏̄ͩ̃̇̈ͤ̐ͥ̚ ҉̴̷̲̳̮̻̥̭͓͎͎̰͕̪̲̙̱̙͍̞̭̥̙̟̤͈͕͖̹̯͔̹̤̜̭̙͉ͅͅs̡̺̭̯̬̗̹̰̭͙̝̹̙̝̰̙̠̰̥̭̪̬̻͕̞̫̟͔̥̳̪̥̣̪̱̬̹̥̘̦͖̦͈̞͙̟̭̫̟̬̗͕̗̤̘̭̮͓̜̗̰̣͛̋̍̽̍ͧ̏ͤ͐ͪ́͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅt̵̷̙͉͔̥̭̪̤̩͕͉̘̤͎̙̤̼̥̻͙͕͇͇̯̯̫͎̳͓͖͎̲̮̹̮͇̤͎̲̤͔̙͖̝̥͊̐̃ͩ̋͊̕͜͠ì̶̡̡̦̼̱͙̻̖̪̹͕̓̽͛͊͛̈̇ņ̠̯͉͎̣̮̥̫͕͓̝͍̫̣̹̙̪͓͉̥̥̤̞͎̮̱͈̩̩̭͈̙͇̠͙̬͖͕̝̮͉̫̫͔͕̗̭͔͚̼͖̳̘̫̹̤̑̂ͯ͐̅̍ͪͦ̍͐̒ͥ̇͆ͨ̊ͭͨ̀͘͟͠g̴̨̤̯̞̘̭̬͈̼͉̠̱̘͚̠̙̼̪̺̗͙͕͖̼͔̻͒̄̑̊̈ͨͦ͗̊̔̐ͤ̚͢͝ ̵̧̘̟̣͖͇̘̦̹̺͍̮̼̜̙̼̹̗̗͈̺͙̗͎̯̥̮͙̫̠̟̱̳͈̺̥̭͕͚͇͎̟͔̘̤̠͕͍̗̯̻̯̖̂̈̌ͯ̒́͌ͬ̀ͥ̾̔͋ͬ́͢͝ͅţ̷̻͎̳̝̱̗̞͈̺̠̟̞̖̬͚͇̥̋̑͗͌ͨ̈̈̌ͤ̽̇̓ͮ͘͜e̿ͨ̏̃̑́ ҉̸̨͉̙̭̭͎̫̜̣̫͎̗͖̜̰̥͉̮̟̱̰̩̜̳̳̝̫͔̯͚̺̮̮̼̝̲̣̞͉̟͍̣̣͢ŝ͕̥̜̮̰̝̼̪͔̘̹̜͈̹̭͉̯̯̜̳̝̜̪̦̤̤͈̙̖̘̹̰̰̺̜̮̯̭̪͚̩̘̝̺͖̪͇̙̹̯̜̰̮̠̗̜̹̫̥̟̲̗ͮ̊̈ͬ̑ͧ̽̾͘͞ͅͅţ̸̢̤̖̥̣̦̮̺͔̼̘͚̲͚͛ͦ͒ͭ̔̃ͪ̍ͬ̊̀͒̈ͫͤ͗͌̃͠i̺̠̠͈̰̗͕̦̗̮̜̪̫̮͖͙͖͍̩͎̹̼̭̣̼͖̼̣̺͇̰͕̗̼̪̞̪͓͇̺̠̜͙̹͎͈̘̞̞̖̼̭̹̹̯̰̹̟̲ͥ̉̏ͬ̽ͯ̂̅̄ͬͧ͊͜͟ͅͅn̶̍͑̎̃ͮͮͮ͆̂ͨ̐̈͂ͭͭ̔͗̾͝ ҉̴̪̞̖͙͓̼͉̗͕̫̰̪̜̣̝͈̺͎̮͍͓̘̱͓͔̠̣̱̣̼̮͕̼̫̪̝͉̥̖͔̝͔̫̭ͅḡ̿ͫ̒͊̊͒͠ ҉̢͈̩̞̮̖͖͕͈̩̙̝̙͎̙̰̱̻̞̗̘̣͈̣̰̥̘͍͙͔̙̝̱͚͎̬̙̭͍̱̜̮̼̭͇̙̗̮͟ͅͅ
t̵̷̛̰͔͕͎͎͔̙̺̭͖̜̺͔͇͉͚̘͖̪̱̞̰̭̜̰͚͍̦̤̬̬̗̜̱̝̩͍͎̟̹̗̯̳̝̲͚̿̂ͬͥ͋̌̊̾̔́͢ͅͅͅę̴̧̟͍̱̥̖̼̘̮͖͑͐͛̆ͥ̅͊͛͠ͅs̛ͪ̅̿͆̄̐͛̍͒ͥ̒̅̏̎̍̍̄͢ ҉͖̖̮̰̙̤̖̣͉ṭ̵͇̟̩̖̬̙̯̼̼̎ͦͬ͂ͪͥ̌ͯ̀́̚i̵̸̧̨̹͈̪̝̗̬̠̳̠̰̱̥̜͙̘̟͉̺̦̭̙͙̠̻̜̦̳̞͇͇̯̜̜̥͇̳͚͖͇̹̜̬͎̤̪̱͈̜͐̎̂̿̊ͤ̑̐͌̇̚ͅn̷̮͚͎̦̬̬͈̞̺͈͖͎̞̠̱̥̠̜̤̱͓̭̪͖̤̣̦̰̝̹͍̜̘̪̬͈̄̑̾ͤͥͩ̽͆̾̀̚͜ģ̧͕̼͇̥̖͉̞̺̩̮̰̦͉̯͓̦̥̯̫͕͚̯̮͕̳͇̝͚̫̟̼͓̞͔͇̼̪̾͐͋̏̓͘͝͠ ͍͎͓̝͙̝̯̟͍̫͍̠̩̝̖̱͉̪͕͓̯̼̝̼̜̯͎̭̬͉̱̝̼͎̬͈͈̫͎̙̖̟̫͖̝̘͇͈̠͑̉͂̃̒̔ͤ̆͊͛̀͘ͅͅͅt̵̵̵̺͕̱͙̰̼̹͇̭͔̬̞̣͔͇̼͙͍͖̺̰͓͔͙̍ͨ̊̔̊ͬͯͦͬ̉̂͆͗͞ͅͅe̢̦̘̩̘͕̰͎̲̻͙̦̣̪̬͖͈̯̭̬̫̱̯͓̤̣͓̤̠̳̱̼̠̹̭̲̰̣̱͇͚͈̞͔͚̻̝̘̱͎̙̩̼͚̠͎̻͓͗͊͑ͩ̀͌͛͌͒ͩ̐͆͛̆͜ͅͅͅͅs̢͉̦͔̙̮̳̰͍̭͕͍̳̟̹̜̹̬̲͍̻͙̤̺͔͉̮̘̖̟̙ͪͩͪͪ͘͘ͅt̷̶̡̥̜̱̪̪͕̦̯͇̫̠͔̯̦̤̖͚̰̳̟̙̙̱̺͇̙̱̖̦̻̺̯̟͚̜̠̣̲̗̰͔̙͔͇̖͚̺̙̦̝̳͇̣̖̮̲̝̯͙̯̼ͩ̒̂̑͌̓͐̌͐̊͌̀̈ͦ̕i͇̗̮̲͕̮̹̯̟͓̬̘͙̞̱̠̤̣͍͔̩̠͔̺͉͚͎͈̥̭̙̤̮̫̩͓̼̗̙͙̼̞̦͉͉̠̩̙̍ͭ͛ͥ̄̈ͫ̽ͬ̕͘͟͡ͅn̷̯͇̻̫̭̣̺͖̙͈͖̰̝̣̪̟͈̭̯͕͙̗͉͓͖̻̬͈͎̻̮͖͕͎ͣͭͯͤ̿̾̅͂͋ͮ̀͘͟͞g̡̻̩̬̥̳͉̣͇̼̰̭͖͕͍̍̄ͦ̔̌̀̋̽ͬͨ̎͆ͨ͊̈̍́̕͠ ̭̩̞̣͇̦̦̜͍̠͙̠̮̝͉̦̫̝͇̘͍͖̤̙͙̥̲̩̙͍̲͍̫̥̥̪͖̩̥̞̊ͭ͆̑ͨ̽ͯ̌ͮͫ͂͐̏ͫ͒ͮ̃̚̚̕͞ͅţ̷̗͉̝͓̙̠̱͎̙̰̹͖̣̘̜̪̬̫̳̲̜͚̜̲̼̱̤̫̝̭̜̺̼͓̮̗̙̲̑ͬ̋̓͂͌̏͋̀e̶̵̸͚̲͍͎̭̭͇͕̼͖̳̱̪̝̖͈͕̬͈̳̍ͪ̅ͩ͗͆͜͝s̷̟̼̳͓͎̬̩͎͎̣̦̟̺͓͙̝̹̯̭̣̭̖̣͙̫̗͖͔̟͈͍̫̯̜͇͕͖̱̲̜ͤ̎̌͒̈̈̋ͮ͊͑ͬ̓́ͩ̕͜͡ͅţ̷̸̷̩͔̳̲̙̮͈̼͓͖͎͚͎̞̠̙̩̬̗̲̜͉̥͍̯̻̩̖̳̭̥̦͍̳̱̖̖̯̖͉͕̮̞̤̜̩̬̘̱͓̪͈̼̖͗͊̃̊ͨ̇̉̓ͤͯ̂͌͑̋͞i̢̱͓̲̮͇̻̫͉̰̲͓̭̫̺̞̤̘͙̦̬̮̩͖͓̪̠͈͇̣͙̳̳̗̺̜̜̮̗͖͍̼̮͙̬͇͖̱͇̱͎̦̳̦̙̜̗ͤ̎̊͌ͤ̓̿̽͛ͪ́͝͡ņ̡̮͕͎̯̬̬͔̺̫͙̰̲̘͈͉̱͔̬̤̹͚̯͖̟̺͓̫̻͉̩̒ͦͯ̆̐̄͐ͤͭͮͫ̊̇̇ͥ͛̚͝g̢̤͇̼͓͙̣̗̙͕̬̮͍͎̲̿͛̑̽̀̂̉̔͑̓̾̉̈̾ͫ̈͗͌̚͠ ̸̧̟̻̥͖̏̌̈͒̆͗͂̀́͜͝t̵͓̥̮̟̙̭͙̮͙̭̲̺̝͎̝̱̯̠̥̣̪̥̥̞̺̺̖̺̼̖̝͇̘̩̠̮͖̠͔̳͈̩̮͕̟̺͕̣̬̟̥̋̀̑̄́ͧ̍͊̀̀͟͞ͅe̔́̍̾ͬ̋͌ ҉̸̢̀ ҉̫͖̤̘͉̳̯͕͇̹̤͓̳̺̰̻̟̬̞s̢̳̬͖͖̭͙̤̮̺̗̼̪͍̬̠̜̘͍̰̣͈̪̥̱̫̤̼̣̞̬͚͓͔̙̺̤͉̙͚̦͕̖̜̤̙̱̞̹̤͕̙̪̱͔̮̭̰̲̺͚̮̥̄̑ͬ̌̍̆̓̅ͩͥ̏̂ͤ͂͑̋̾̀͢͠ͅͅͅt̸̷̬̩̹̺͔͔̭̏̎͗͆͆ͯ̚͟͞i̜̘̼̜̦͈͍̲̯͎͚̝̜̩̤̞͉̘͎͚̠̝͔̯͇͉̱ͥ͑ͦͪ͢͟ͅͅn̴͕̜͕̜̭̙̪͎̪̳̹̣̞̟͉͈̲̯͙̬͕̟͉̫̗̭̺̜͒ͯ͐̆͆͐̇̓͝ͅͅg̫̗͓̝̺̬͔̰͕̱̳̹̼̗̗̳̻͇̹͍̟͙̟̘͇̪͔̦̻̜̙͙̼͎̪̊ͮͦ͆̌́̚̕ ̸̧͚͈̠̺͖̳̮̩̞̘̞̗̘͚͕̳̫͉̟̠͖̙̺͕̬̭̤̻̼͚̬̹͙͍͓̺̳̣̣̼̮̗̯̱̼͎̹͚͈̝̻̰̹̩͕̫̟̦̼̣̦̖̱̜̃ͣ̋͗̈͒͒ͣ͡͞ͅͅṭ̨̙̦͍͔̝̩͔͕̦͔̮̖̝̰̥̣̭̱̮͍̞͈̞̭̯̬̮͇͕̺̯̹̗͇̩̺̥̟̯̯̻ͪ̔ͤ͗ͩ͊̀̑̾ͬͬ́͠͞e̿͛̎̆̈ͯͫ̂̈̆ͤ̈ͯ͐ ҉̧̼̻̩̳̟̰̪̯͕̣̦̠̟͇͔̦̪̮̯͓͢͜ș̢̢̣̲̭̭̺͚̹͈̩̲̰̳͓̳͚̬̮̖̖̺̤̖̻̣̗̭̥̱͎̰̞̖̗͙̠͎̭̦̠̥̳̗̩̞̣͇͐̄̔̑̒ͦ̆́͊͝ͅt̨̘̫͚̙̔̔ͨ̆̓͞͞i̴̵̡̼͎̙̬̦̪̮̳̘̬̲̘̣̞̣̱ͮ̈̐ͮ̄̈ͨ͌͊ͯ̊̈ͨ̂͐ͧ̎ͧ́n̨̼̞̩̬͈͙̮̮͍͉̝̮͇̜̞̦͇̻͈̦̤̱͙̜͇͉̻̪̩̹̟̟̣̤ͦ͑̋ͨ̎͠ͅͅg̸̶̮̗͉̜̱͓̮̠̹͕̟̼͔̹̗̥̞͓͚̯̦̣̮͔͙̠̟͍͖̳͖̤̭̼̹̻̖̯̟͖̟̪͓̜̯̺̗̤͕̰̞̣̼̓͛ͩ̈̓̐̊͑̾̍̕͜͝ͅͅͅͅ ̟̥̪͍̰͇̙̟̝̺͍͍͍͖͈̮͖͓̱̪̪̯̗̞̽́ͭͤ̍ͧ̒͒͌̽̀̕͝͞ͅt̷̛͍͓̼̺͈̓ͥ͐̓ͯͪ͒̈̐ͫ̒̅ͯ̈̃͝e̷̫͙͔̯͎̦͔͍͇̤̫̱͕̻͇͙̖̔̽̑̂̽͊̆̔ͣ̌̓ͬ̂ͬ͗ͧ̑́s̶̵̴̸̢̟̣̭̹̪̟̜̼̤͙̙̫̞̲͈͙̤̼̦̘̟̩̅ͧ̎́̓̿̉ͬ̌̑ͤ̂̚ͅt̷̛̹͚̞̩̹͉͑ͣ̾͊͠i̶̧̠̯͖̺̫̯̠̜̠̘̫͉͔̦̜̯͈̱̪̗̱͙͚͕̼͕̯̤̙ͣ͒̾͌̅̂͌ͮ̓̓̒̀̀̚͢͢ͅͅn̶ͬ͋ͤ̎̽ͦ̍̍͛͡ ҉̧̰͇̻̝̰̦̲̝͎̯͉̺͙̼̦̰̞̫g̢͕͖̞̜̠͍͕̤͇͔̤̠̲̰̘̲̹̖̤̼̼̙̻̻̖͉̩̥̯ͩ̂̈̏̀ͬ̚͘͜ ̝̣̫͕͚͓̺̮̟̮͖̘̱͙͇̺͙͕̝̥̻̭̥̳͓̗͚͉͉̦̗̟͍̥͖͉̳̞͍̹̟̠̗̙͓̩̼̼̫͓̗̲͉̻͓̱̿̄̈ͣ̊͌̇̒ͬ͌ͧ̆ͪͪ̚͟͠t̸ͤͤ̿͋ͥ͆̉̌̎̋̈ͪ̆ͨ̽́ ҉̝̳̼̘͈̥̣̤̼̘͞ȩ̴͍̜͍̱̼̹̪̖̟͔̩̜̝̜͍͎̙̼̗̘̘̜̠͙̟͙̬̦̯̳͈͓͈̜̯̝̝͔̹̳̩̥͍̺͇͕̰̫̱̹̦̜̃̇̂̀́̓̑̒́͘͘ͅͅs̺̖̮̺̥̺̩̱̭̰̫͍͙͉̩̼̗̼͕͇̳̥̮͔̩̻̠͉͙͖̱̣̜̬̝̯̦͖̝͙̱̲̰̬̹̮͚̼̲ͪ́͑͗̆̑ͦ̌͆̎̾ͧ̚͢͝ͅͅt̴̶̢̺̠͓̬̘̠͍̻̞̟͈̜̙̬̥̜̺̞̪̜̯͔̩̪̲͎̙̞̺̺̝ͧͯ̇̿̃̂̊͊̀͘ͅͅi̶̬̘͓̪̻̪̗̰͈̱̜̗̜̠̜͕̦͖̝̘͚̯̜̟͕͇̖̲̹̗͎̝̰̻̺̭͍̳͇̖͔̦͈̺̙̩̝̹̖̙̻̹̹̬̪̝ͭ̐ͬ͗͂͗̔̅ͭ̐ͤ͌͗͛̄ͫ͢͢ͅn̵̵̳̭̫̻̳̼̪̲̝͔̫̘̝̮̯̤̩͉̗͎͚̣̻͍͚̰̫̤̣̙̤͚̭̯͖̤͇̝̝̳̉͒̓̏͢͜g̵̺͖̗̥͙͔̝͖͑ͬͫ̇̾̂̄̃ͯ̚̚͡ͅ
t̶̬̰̱̼̤̱̬ͫ̓̏ͤ̃̕͘̕ê̵̘̜̯͇̲̤̟̹͖̤̳͉̥̠͍̲̭̱̣̭̘̥̗͉̱̰̤̤̟͇̬͖̦̺̰̘͚̱̭̖̠̜͔̱̲̝̮̟̼̦̩͙̳͙̤͖͇̓͒̒͂͒́͝ͅs̴̲̬̫̲̬̗̳̻͉̝̝̻̗͔̫̯̹̯͕̖̙̗̬͍̱̝̤͇̫̱͓̠̫̼͚̯͇̠̯͚̦̟̬̠͍̩̼̰͈̻̠͕̣̯̻̓̋͒ͫͭͮ̐͌͟͠͞ͅͅt̿͊̈̊ͪ͘͘͠ ҉̣̞̺̱͈̘̼̲̰͙̤̞͖͔͉͔͚̬͉̱͖̣̥̤͍̦̦͙̖̬̣͘i̴̡̪̣̪̲̥̖͔̱͈̬̜̖̩̱̱̘̜̝̱̦̘̖̩̳̣̬͚̩͉̥ͦ̃̎̓͊͐̂͌̀̚͘ͅͅn̶̢͈̟͇̘̟͉̻͚̲̣͎̣͓͕̹̹̺͓̱͍̼̠̟̞͉͎͔͙̼̙̖̯̰͈̹̳͙̲̥͎̖̳͙̻̼ͯ͌̋͐̍͋̓͂ͨͪͬ͂͌͝g̶̨̨̨̨͖͙͇̤̑ͣͮ̓̾͐͌͒̃̽ͩ̀ͮͩ͊͒̀ͩ̿ͅ ̸̧̛͕̞̻̹͔͕̘̼͔͇̤͈̤̣̮̜̬̭͙͔̥̼̠̤͕̲̙̖͈̤̫͚̯͚͉̘̣̦̮̬̦̻̗͉͈̣̖̬͖̯͙̞̦͙̣͖̣̣̺̒ͪ͗͌̒ͫ̾ͥ͢ͅͅt̵̷͔̼̖͕̰͚̰͔͈͎͕̹͇̞͙̤̩̻̠̘͇͇̠̠̲͉̜̟̳̬̖͉̼̜̖͍̪̼̲̲̳͎̘͎̝̠̜̯͙̝͇̹͇͉̭̉̓͆ͫ̋́̅ͬ̉̿ͧͪ̀̕͝ͅͅe̷̢̩͚̞̟̤̠͍̖̹̻̠̫͔̩̯̤͖̻͕̖͇̘͓̿̊͑̋ͩ͜s̡͉͈̙̠͔̘̹̠̫͚̮̻̯̦͇̖̤̰͇̫̙̲̫̼̹̱̰̤̠͚͕̬̤̱͉͖̫̻̬̬̱̘̰̝̬̟̺̮̖̟̘̣̯͈̻̙̫͖͚̻̫̱ͨ̎̔̆̃̇̏̈ͥͨ͂ͣ̿̅̀͊̓ͣ͘͟͝͠ͅͅt͙͈̝̦̖̳̠͈̺̙͎͉̘̫̘͓̫̤͑ͦ̏̓̅ͪͤ̈ͥ̀̚̚͘͝͠͞ͅi̴̢̿͛͋̈ͮ͐̾́ͫ͑ͦ̃̚͜ ҉̶̥̣̥͔͔̘̩͔͍̭̲̬̗̥̥͕͇̠ň̴̝͕͉͕͎͔̩̦͓͉͓̪̯͇̳̩̠͉̩͕̘̜͖̹̘̱͓̺̻̹̯͙̤̹̞̤̪̪̗͔͕̝͉̙̺͓͔̪̱̪̤̲̖ͫ̔̓̀̂̉̑̓̒͒́͘͢͞ͅͅͅg̛͚͕̱̖͙͚̃̂̄ͪ̎́̾̚͘ͅ ̵̉̑́͒͒ ҉̧̛̗͈̦͉̠̥̘̘̭̟̲̼̮̠̘͈͈̦̞̣̺̲͈̘͚̰̩̹̹̰̻̮̺̩̰̰̼̤̭̘̞̝̜̻t̵͙̤̘͎͇̙̙̭̖͕͔̗̍̈̅̌̏͛̀̃̂͊͛́̚͝e̵̡̮̘̠̠͙̫̥͇͈̥̞̻̖̊̎̂́ͬͨ̄̏́̚̚͢͡s̶͔͈͖͇̟̺͓͓̟̯̣̭̹͙͔̳͎͉̺̦͚̩̯̯͈̞̝͕͈̠̙̬̣̘͙̯̺̪̩̫̜̗̭̮̳̦̭͇̣͚̼̟̞̻̥͓̫̼̜̬̜̒͛ͦ́͒͛̇ͨͩ̅ͭ͆ͮ̌̔̎̎́̚̕͡ͅͅtͧͭ̅̇̌̇̋̀́ͪ͗ͣ́̀ͥͩ̕̕ ҉͔͔̥͈i̢̨̡̖̣̜̘͇ͦͥͨͤ̓̾ͨͪ̐̀ͪ̾ͣ̐̎͒͡͠ͅn̶̓ͪ̄̈ͫ̒̿̌ ҉̼͙̱̻͔̥̭̲̠͍̖̩͓͖͍͉̫̙͙̺͇͚̱̫ͅͅĝ̞̝̤̞͔̪͉̜͈̜̪̳̼̘̠̠̥̩̫̪̞͎̜̯̺̝̠͇͇̝̞̺̞̪̅ͨ͑͊̕͘ͅ ̶̶̛̼̘̝̺̤͔̝̞̳̻͍̞̟̲̦͎̬̮̳̻̼̥̮̜̳̩̜̦̦̙̹͉͔̥͖͉̺̩͇̙͎͚͈̲̣̤̤͔̗͎͉̺̙͓̤̗̞̺̗̼̦̞͆̇ͯ̐̔ͣ̍͆̽ͨ͆̃͊̄ͪ̓͡ͅt̴̋ͣ̎̈͊ͫ̍̓͐ͭ̉͟ ҉̤͖̣͕̬̤̩̱̠͍͉͓̹̹̫̜̻͈̟͍̝̗̟͇̦̻̲̦̭̼̖̼̹̣̠̰͎͙͉̱̠̘̬̮̬̱̯̥̯͇͍͕͈ͅe̷̵͖̘͕̱̤͔̭̣͙̮͎͚̝̱͙̝̗̩̖̟̖͍̗̣̰̭̲̪͕͇̙̹̙͚̣͕̖̻̤͔̝̤͍̣̬̰̭̫͖͍̬̬͍̜͛̀̾̋̒͒͂͋̔ͪ͘͠ͅş̷̛̜̺̞̰̗̪̹͖̗̗̪͕̠̯͈͍̗̳̩̙̗̜͍͖͇͕̱̭̫̦̜͕͈̝̥̭̮̘͉̩͚̬͈̙̮͓̭̦̃̑̓͌̔́̚͠ͅt̛̪̘̙͇͙͕̤̳͈͇͙̼̗̫̬̮̤̥͍̪̠̖̖̲̼̘̮̾̒̓̄̒͛ͪ͆ͮ̕ͅi̢̪̲̖͉̠͔͉̙̪̫̤͇͈̙̖̭͔͖͔̼̗̪̗͔̖̼͇͚̻̣͓̥̮͚̜͇̪̝̯̟̰̟̰̫͍̝̯͒͗̎͂̈̍ͩͦͥ̀ͣ̎͞ͅn̢̡̟͖͓̟̱͙̱̞͈̮̣̞̹͎͓̫͍̺̯̤̤̙̥̦͖̭͙̹̰̞̯̣͙̭̖͍̼͕͇̮̺͚̪͚̗̖̹̺͉͍͈͙͎̼̣̬̫̝ͤ͆͒͐̈̈ͩ̍̈̂̑ͦͤ̎́͜͝ͅͅͅͅg̡̖̲̹̣̠͉̥̙͔̲̱̙̱̩̫̟̰̗̥͎̹̹̤̙̫̱̦͇̣̪̞̘̺̥̗̲̝̭͒ͩ̑̉̓͊̊̇͝͝͡ ̶̨̺̥̙̱͙͙̜̱̀̌ͩͬ͗ͩ̃͊̍̾̀͢ţ̟̣̗̲̦̩͍̩̣͎̝̦̘̜̟̭͚͎͙̜͔͍̞͕̟̖͖͉̭̼̩̖̩͉̺͉͕̯̣͚͕͖͔̯̜̭̙̰̼̟͉̮̻̭͇̗̱͕͕̱̓ͪ͂̈̎͠ͅͅͅe̝͖̜͔̳̫̙̼̫̬̝͖̰̳͍̯̰̬̠̻̱̗̗͔̞̲̭̜̰̹̙̯̹̘͈̞̻̠͇͓̫̤͗ͬ̀̆̉͗̔̄̑̄͗̈̿͢͢s̴̡͖̯̪̦͇͉̞͔͕͔̻̟̯̖̾͑̎͊͑̿̌ͭ̋̂ͭͣ̆͛̚͝t̴͈̤̩̟͖̘͚̮͕̦̙͍͓̝͎̹̮͚͎͍͇̗̗̰̱̪̹̗̣̦̲͙͈͔̳͍̺̱͍͈͓̱̼̞͚͉͈͔̻̺͈̙̪͔ͩͤͣ͋ͬͤ̌͑̇̑̉̏ͤ̀̐̅̍̊͜͜͞ͅͅͅį͓̺̫͚̩̒͂̓̈ͯ̏ͥ̍ͥ̑ͤ̀̉ͮͣ̈̍̚͡ͅn̪̩̭̯̪̖̫̱̗͈͙̣̲̭̹̲̞̺̪̠̰͒͐̊̆ͣ͌ͫ̽̃͛̒͋ͯ́͡ͅg̛̼̫̟̠̪̺̖̖̺̹̹̗̩̗̭͕̖̗̟̥̖͈͖̬̪͉̦̳͇̰̣͎̮͕̟̟͙͇̤̲͕̬̗̣̘̙͈̘̦̥͉͓̳̟͔͈̺̲̹̬͈͚̫̲̩͉ͥͯ͆̓̇ͫͨ͜͡͞ ̆̅̆͗ͪ ҉̸̡ ҉̨͈̙̫͔͓̟̟̱̥͍͎͓͎̻͓̳̰̤̙͙̙͚̳̮̺̪̠̣̯̣̗̪̬̱̙̲̙̖͖̣̗̙̝͈̜̩͚̮͕ͅt̶̵͕͖͖̰̣̭͊̓͐ͬ̓͂͑̐̒̒͗́ͅe̦̥͙̲͇̥̟̻͇̦̣͓̩̪̼̳̙͈̗͍̱̥̲̙̟̻̪͍̺͔̫̼̼̞͍̻͓̪̪͇̲̜̠͕͎̩͈̰͚͓͕̝̞̱͖̹̳̻̦͍ͧͣͥ̃́̐ͣͩͥ̃́͐̿́͡ͅͅs͕̮͚͎͎͉̜̤͉̙̼̭̙͙̱̯̭̟̲̞̫̜̰̳̲̳͚̪̫͙̗̖̹͚͉̹̙̹͚̭͔̜̻̘̘͌ͯͩ̌̋̎͘̕tͨ̃͗̂̿ͤͮͮͮͨ͐ͮͭͭͬͨͥ ҉̢̗͎͕͓͙̬͔̱̝͈̩͎̱̙͇̬́͢͞ï͔̯̮̳̫͈͓̠̥͇̮̖̫͔̣͈̿ͩ̉̄̓̈ͭ̌͘͢ͅͅṉ̷̡͚̬̣̻̥͕̖̥̠̦̩̺̤͖̘͕̜̻̣̳̯̦̞͚̝̜̠͉͙̥̔͐͑͛́ͨͣ̀̐̍̊ͧ͊̓͛̃͊́ģ̸̨̦̱͕̫͎̖̜̰͂̊̏̄ͧͭ͐͋̏ ̷͎̬̭̹̺̞͙̟̹̟̰̰̠͖̥̳̞̟͖̻̠̱̝̘̠̪̪̼̼͉̙̫̪̩̠̤̗̭̣̪͚͇̮̺̙̹̥̥͎̪̟͚͖̗̘̻̙̱͔͛̅͛̈ͬͧ́͝͡ͅͅͅt̵̡̛͎̟̘͔̩̤͕͚̬̖͕͎̹̯̙͍͎̪̮͙̞͈̲͓͚͉̬͔̠̞͍̦̥̱̜̩͇͙̹͕̻̖̼̺̟̖̗̤̓ͫ̅ͬ͜͡e̵͉͎͇̠̥̘̙͙̖̤͍̥̖̼͂͐ͦ̂ͤͧ̌́ͧ̉̓̀͝ṣ̷̡̺̘̦͕̲̝̯̞̮͙̳̪̱̫̮̩̙̞̠̰̥̻͎̰̩̟̥̱̣͓͚̮̱̳̜̬̱͇̤ͥ̓ͤ̒̔̎̆͒ͯ̈͑͆̈ͭ̓̚̚ͅͅͅt͌̽ͬ̋̅̋̍͒̄̆͛̚̕ ҉̷̦͙̰͍̞̖̫̭͇̪̻̦͙͍̩͇̬̦͓͉̞̫̯̹̯͕̺̮̘͈̺̞̩͇͙̣̰̖̦͉̪͍̗̹̖͖̪̭̱̣̪̟̯̰͙̘̼͍̖̹̱̙͕̗͍͞i̵͈̘̣̘̟̖̭͉̤͙̤̫̻̜͖͉̱̫̤̥̖̮͈̘̰͈̩̤ͣͧ͛ͦ̈ͯ͘͟ņ͚̦̯̗̠̪̦͕̬͎̙͇̝͆ͬ͑̎̋͂̓̌̂̀̚͢͢g̨̙̭̥͙̝͚̟̦̘̤͚̝̩̼͎̤͇̗̼̟̫̪̰̗̮̻̜͓̳͔̲͔̥͇̙̩͈͙̟͚̞̳̟̯͙͇͖̻̤̺̗͔̙̻͆̍ͬ͆̃͐͊̈ͤ́ͯ͌̉͠ͅͅ
t̿̆͌͒ͩ͒̈̾̓̊ͥ̌͑̓͋́̚̕͘ ҉͈̖̬̫̟̮̭͙̦̘̘̜̞̣̺͚͚̻̺̳̩̖͉̘̖͔̬͖̹̗̻͕͉̖̟̠̝̱̪̥̘̠̩̤͢ͅͅͅe̙͖̗̠̗̹̗̯̜̗̞͚̜͔̝͉̠̪̠̹͙̹͈̝͎̹͇̩̭̬̙̟̣̬̥̠̯̥͇̩̥̱̻͚͇̖̺̫ͭͣ̌ͣ̎̓̈ͨͣ̍̿͒ͪ͛̚̕͠ͅs̴̷̨̙̬̝̘̬̤͔̱̜̟̪̘̻̗͓̮̭͍͙̱͇̫̟̟̞̥͚͓̟̗̬͓̩͖̤͎̺̥̼̥͙̖̙̖̩̲͙̺ͣ̈ͣͣͯ̍̓̃̽͑͆ͪ̌͛ͩͫ̾̄̚͢͞t̶̻̜̬͇̩̣̺̳̰͚̙͉͕̱̤̺̘̦̼̖̔̋̆̉͂̋̃͌̽ͭ̄ͫͮͭ̓͛͠i̶̲̤̹͎̦̳͉̝͈̣̳̟̳͕̥͍̝̺̮͔̪͍̦ͮͪͮͣͣ̉̿̃̈̑̈͠͞͝ͅṋ̳͇̠̞͔̲̳̣̻̜̱̩̬͇̹͓͕̰̘̰̜̟̯̘̻͉̼̣̲̼͎͓͍͚͍̖̻̰̟̼̼͎̜̲̘̩̞̣̯̙͎͉̭̙͉̜͍̅̄ͦ̽̅ͭ̕͢͡ͅͅͅͅͅg̵̷͕͙̹̫̯̟̣̫͙̼̮̘͉͕̞͕̘͓̟̮͙̫̹̭̳̜̫̘̗̪͇̞̗͖̞̥̬͑̈̈̈͋̑͞ͅ ̴̷̨͍̣̹̖̀͌̎̈͛̓̽ͭ̅̔͑͒ͮ̃̈̔̆̚̚͟t̅̊͋̋ͬ̒ ҉͍̥̥̣̲̲͎͍͟ȩ̛̱̮̤͇̺̺̲̦̬̘̹̣̖̜̹͎̳͈̻̬͖̖̖͍͔͍̤̳̭͎͉̠͍̘̜͍̻͖̬̻̳͙͚̜̠̲̻̽̌̾ͭ̏́s̡͇̝̭̪̙̫̲͎̹͚̺̜̬̼̼̜̦͕̜͕̯͕͖̼̯̥̠͈̲̮͈̻̰͖̞͚͉͕̳̞̠̮̣̗̥͎̹͇̟̝̙̪͍̻̞̘͚͕͇̦̼̖̖̪̉̇͆̒ͭͥ̏̃͌ͯ͟͡ͅͅͅṱ̸̱͚̜͎̦͍̜̗̫̲̼͖̺̳̲̮̱͎̳͔͇͖̞̗̭͍̦̮̖͖͈͍͎̮͕͚̳͚̖͉̦̬̳̰̰̱̭̳͕̙̭̖̼̻̟̩̝̬͍͉ͣͣ̌̊̍ͬ̓ͨͮ̒̾̚͠ͅͅiͫ̽ͩͫ̑ͤ̀̚̚͡ ҉̦̯̫̤͇͇̮̪̙͉̞̺̰̞͔͇̲̖̭̱͉̣͔̗͉͈̞̯̮͈͇n̵̦͙͖̞̟͖̼͇̣̬̹̦̯̞̳̖̮̬̲̺̙̞͉͍͇̹̹̱̣͙̱̣̥͉̩̠͉͉̮͇͉̜̰̹̱̫̬̬̊̍ͫͨ̍͛͂͗̌̆ͬ̀͜͡ͅģ̶̩͚͎̰͈͓̖̳̤̖̪̞̜͇̰͈̳̞̬͙͈̣̰̯̱̤̤͎͔̜̳̣͚͖͎̫͓̻̲̬̖̟̪̱̹̬̖̻̲͎͔̜̩̲̪̝̰͉̝̜̮̱̟͖ͥ̒̈̿̈̾̇ͭ͛̑ͬͨ̍̾̌͑ͫͫ͂ͅͅͅ ̸̴̟͖̭͕̜͔̠̣̤̜̮͎͙̯͎̟͍̦̼͓͙̥͈̙̰̼̻̟̪̺͚̗̦̘̠͙̮͈̥̣̻̼̦̯̳̲̰͖͎̪̬͎̏̍͆͛̿͐ͯͩͦ͢ͅt̷̶̰͔̹͓̞̝̣͕̤̣̣͚̯̗̗̙̠͓̬̜͕̭͕͙̠̤̤̮̯̪͚̭͙̭̯̘̭̰͎̙͚̰̦̦͕̠͉͙̖̜̖̘̞̲̲͍͙̝̞̻̗̤̀̔̎̓͌̆̎̾́̓ͅͅͅͅe̶̵͇̪̩̲̲̣͎̦̤̰͕̼̟͚̥̘͎͉̦̮̘͙̞͕̞̙̼̰̘̱̲̦͖̱̫̙͔̳̞̪̝̻͈̞͈͍̼̗̥͉ͦ̆ͬ̈ͮ̅ͭͥͮͫ͆̆̐ͨ̈̈͛́̚͠͠ͅs
```

My package.json file:

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^37.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^13.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  }
```

The karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            jasmine: {
                // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
                // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
                // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
                // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
            },
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        jasmineHtmlReporter: {
            suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage/ngx-persian'),
            subdir: '.',
            reporters: [
                {type: 'html'},
                {type: 'text-summary'}
            ]
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is:

1.) Create a blank Angular 13 project.

2.) Run npm run test.

3.) See the output of the terminal is proper.

If the output of the terminal is proper, that means it is most likely a configuration problem when going from 11 to 13. If it's not proper, it could be the terminal/your computer. Try doing it in a different computer.

If it is proper on a blank Angular 13 project, look at the blank Angular 13 project and make sure you have the same exact things.

1.) Check test.ts to see they are the same.

2.) Check angular.json to see they are identical or the same.

3.) Check package.json to ensure the packages are the same and the versions are the same. The packages in question are `jasmine`, `jasmine-*`, `karma`, `karma-*`, and even the `@angular` ones.

Hopefully that diagnosis helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, this is the blank Angular package I've created and moved my codes to it. But I try running the command on a blank project.